# Rendering PDF in mobile browser

Tags: pdf, rendering

Is there any way of rendering the PDF in mobile browser without downloading them (prompting user to save them on their device) ?

Comment: What are the headers being sent with the PDF?  If there's a `Content-Disposition` header indicating that it's a file to be downloaded, try removing that header.  If there isn't, then it sounds like it's a browser-side setting.

Comment: You can convert your PDF file on a fly into the image and show it on a client side [link](http://is.gd/vWftVT)